# How to set (or reset) line thickness and intensity in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

in the following code:

```
    For i = 1 To j
       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Select
       With Selection
           .MarkerStyle = xlNone
           .Smooth = False
           .MarkerSize = 2
           .Shadow = False
       End With
       With Selection.Border
           .Weight = 1
           .LineStyle = xlContinuous
           Select Case i
              Case 1 To 2
                   .ColorIndex = black
                   .Weight = 4
                   .LineStyle = xlDot
               Case 3
                   .ColorIndex = red
                   .Weight = 5
               Case 4
                   .ColorIndex = light_brown
                   .TintAndShade = 0.5
               Case 5
                   .ColorIndex = dark_blue
                   .TintAndShade = 0.5
               Case 6
                   .ColorIndex = solid_blue
                   .TintAndShade = 0.5
              Case 7
                   .ColorIndex = cyan
                   .TintAndShade = 0.5
              Case 8
                   .ColorIndex = bright_green  'purple
                   .Weight = 5
              Case 9
                   .ColorIndex = bright_green
                   .Weight = 5
              Case Else
                   .ColorIndex = black
                   .Weight = 2
           End Select
       End With
    Next i
```

it stops at case 3 VBA and claims that it is "unable to set the Weight property of the border class"
How can I make different lines with their own thickness and color intensity?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Ensure that you have `.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue`

```
With ActiveChart
    With .SeriesCollection(1)
        With .Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(91, 155, 213)
        End With
        .Border.Weight = 2
    End With
    With .SeriesCollection(2)
        With .Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(91, 155, 213)
        End With
        .Border.Weight = 3
    End With
    With .SeriesCollection(3)
        With .Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(91, 155, 213)
        End With
        .Border.Weight = 4
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Rout Thank you. Your code works. After trying it I changed .border.weight to 5 and it stopped working. Than I dug out Microsoft docs (it wasn't easy because M/S kept sending me around for some reason) and found that value above 4 is invalid. With better docs or error alerts it could been solved with much less hassle for everyone involved. I also found that my code works as well with value =4

Comment: Could you please provide the link of the msdn that says a value above 4 is invalid. I am facing a similar issue